# continuous discrete open map and topological dimension

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there anyone who can help me to answer this question :

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded and connected set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $A\subset \Omega$ be a closed set of Lebesgue measure zero and whose topological dimension is $\leqslant n-2$. Is $\Omega \setminus A$ connected ?